# Optimizing MySQL ORDER BY field of JOINed table

Tags: mysql, database, join, query-optimization

I have the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl1` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `tid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `time` datetime NOT NULL,
 `count` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `tid_uid` (`tid`,`user_id`),
 KEY `tid_time` (`tid`,`time`)
) 

    CREATE TABLE `tbl2` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `field_to_order_by` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
 KEY `field_to_order_by` (`field_to_order_by`)
)
```

I'm trying to perform the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 
LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.user_id=tbl2.user_id 
WHERE tbl1.tid=13 AND time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
ORDER BY tbl2.field_to_order_by DESC LIMIT 200
```

The performance problem I'm facing is due to the `ORDER BY` of the joined table field. If I remove that or even replace it with a `WHERE` condition on the same field I'm getting a massive improvement.

How/Can I achieve reasonable performance with this combination of JOIN and ORDER BY or can this only be solved with de-normalization?

This is the EXPLAIN:

```
id  select_type  table  type    possible_keys     key       key_len  ref           rows     Extra  
1   SIMPLE       tbl1   range   tid_uid,tid_time  tid_time  12       NULL          221664   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort  
1   SIMPLE       tbl2   eq_ref  user_id           user_id   4        tbl1.user_id  1
```

Comment: What proportion of your 200 results would you expect to have no tbl2 records (ie. NULL `tbl2.field_to_order_by`)?

Comment: In what way does replacing an `ORDER BY` with a `WHERE` condition give you the same result?

Comment: @MarkBannister Sorry about that - was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: @BellevueBob It doesn't gave the same result, if it would, I would use it. Just mentioned as a performance check I've done.

Comment: @MarkBannister Re 'What proportion...' - I would expect about 10% to have no tbl2 records. Why?

Comment: Is that 10% of all records, or 10% of the 200 (ie. typically 20 records)? Also, can you include a query plan from your existing query in your question?

Comment: @MarkBannister I've added the explain to the question. I don't know that percentage exactly but I meant 10% of all records, meaning most of the times all 200 will have a value in `tbl2.field_to_order_by`. Can this make any dramatic effect to performance?

Comment: Noam: merge the two tables if it makes sense...

Comment: @Denis doesn't make sense in my case. In general, doing what I'm trying to do, can't be done with MySQL with good performance?

Comment: @Noam: Define *good performance*. How many rows in each of those tables?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' currently the performance is very bad (over 100seconds) when the query matches about 100k rows in tbl1 in the time-frame and tid. Anything to do other than de-normalization? Am I using all the right indexes?

Comment: With around 100k rows, 10% having no tbl2 records, I would therefore expect 10k tbl1 records selected with no tbl2 records - **much** more than 200. I would therefore expect **all** records returned to have NULL `field_to_order_by`, since MySQL returns NULL values first on an ascending sort - see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html . If this is what you want, try adding a `and tbl2.user_id is null` condition to the `where` clause. If you want to explicitly exclude such records, simply use an inner join. Which do you want, and how is performance affected?

Comment: @MarkBannister I'm not looking for the NULL values. When I use WHERE the performance is MUCH better. I assume this is because he is able to use the index for the WHERE field_to_order_by but not for the ORDER BY field_to_order_by. But I don't understand why, unless this is an issue in joined tables.

Comment: Noam, if what you have said so far is correct, your query **will only ever return null tbl2 values**. If you don't want to see them, what happens when you change the join condition to an inner join?

Comment: @MarkBannister I had a missing `DESC` in my question when you saw it, sorry about that. INNER JOINS makes the query a bit more effective. ~90Seconds.

Comment: I guess if you remove LIMIT 200 you will get significantly more than 200 records? 
Have you tried adding an index on tbl2 that has the two fields: (user_id, field_to_order_by)?